# VBA ADOBC secure connection

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I'm working on an Excel client for our company. It requires several connections to a MySql database (which is a PC running Apache Server(XAMPP) located in our office). I'm able to connect remotely and push/pull data fine so development is going good in that respect.

**But, my only concern is how secure the connection is over public networks (i.e. hotels, restaurants, airports)?**

If odbc connection string data is easily sniffed I'll need to find another way. I Hope you can point me in the right direction if that is the case.

Driver: MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver (installed by MySQL Connector)
Provider: MSDASQL

I would like to add remote authentication on startup because it may be required from time-to-time to disable access for a particular user.

**Added:**

Would this secure a connection on public network If I added security certificate on remote server and the Excel client used ssl connection string like so?

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;sslca=c:\cacert.pem;
sslcert=c:\client-cert.pem;sslkey=c:\client-key.pem;sslverify=1;Option=3;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Presumably if folk are connecting from outside of your LAN they are using some type of VPN connection?  That should take care of any security concerns.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not using a VPN. Good idea. I'll do some research on open source vpn options.